# How can I open other people's Outlook from asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using

```
    Dim Outl As Object
    Outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application", "localhost")

    If Outl IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim omsg As Object
        omsg = Outl.CreateItem(0) '=Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem'
        'set message properties here...'
        omsg.Display(True) 'will display message to user
    End If
```

to open outlook but when i host application in iis i got error "Cannot create ActiveX component."
i welcome all suggestion..

Comment: where do you have your web application? on a server or on a normal machine? ussualy servers don't have outlook installed

Comment: Are you trying to open Outlook on the client via code running in IIS?

Comment: yes i am try to open it on client via iis

Comment: but my server have office 2003,so, if there any issue occur if client have office 2010 ?

Comment: is there any other way, because i don't know which version client use

Comment: is there any other way from silver light or java script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is what many virus and malware authors have tried to do. Consequently I don't believe you can. Outlook will block your attempt as it thinks it's malicious.

It may work if the server is running in a trusted zone, but the user will need to change their local IE settings to add your website. If you're trying to show a mail item, try using `a href=mailto:` instead. it's possible to specify subject & body in the link.

Simon

Comment: i don't have idea about that can you give me reference ?

Comment: whoops. badly formatted message didn't show up properly. fixed it now.

Comment: perhaps you can explain how you fixed it? If it was with help from these answers you should accept an answer. I notice you haven't done that yet on any of your questions.

Comment: i use this HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.location='mailto:?subject=Estimate &body=Dear Customer,%0A%0AModule Cost%0A%0APhysician Master%0A%0AInsurance Master%0A%0AVitals%0A%0Atest%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0ATotal Amount: 1018%0A%0ADiscount: 30 Description: %0A%0ANet Amount: 988%0A%0A';</script>")

Comment: give a rate if you think its use full.

Answer (score 0):

Winforms apps (like Outlook) launched in service process will be displayed on an invisible virtual screen. You will only be able to see the side effects of the applications actions, i.e. sending an email.

Also, is this ASP.NET or ASP classic? That CreateObject reminds me more of ASP classic than .NET

You didn't show the rest of the code... If this is not server side code, but instead say a client side VB script sent to the user in HTML, then you will need to sign your code, the user will have to do a lot of configuration to trust your code to launch an ActiveX component. Launching an ActiveX component as if it were a Java Applet is kind of a security risk, since ActiveX, at least originally, wasn't designed to be carefully sandboxed. (But times may have changed, I haven't looked at client side ActiveX embedded in HTML in years)